# Is it possible to scroll the thumbnails carousel with hover on the arrow buttons in Galleria?

Tags: jquery, galleria

In the classic template for Galleria, the thumbnail carousel can be scrolled by clicking on the left and right arrow buttons. Is it possible to make this scroll by hovering over the arrow buttons instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
Galleria.ready(function(){
    this.$('thumb-nav-right , thumb-nav-left').mouseenter(function(){
        this.click();
    });
});
```